# How to convert 'n' objects into an Array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm getting some objects after made a comparison between the api response and today's date:

```
function taffy() {
  var d = new Date();
  $scope.day = d.getDate();
  $scope.month = d.getMonth() + 1;
  $scope.year = d.getFullYear();
  $scope.today = $scope.year + "-" + $scope.month + "-" + $scope.day + "T00:00:00";
}

function getBackAll() {
  $http.get('api/Invoice?')
    .then(function(data) {
      $scope.amadeus = data.data.Response;

      for (var i = 0; i < $scope.amadeus.length; i++) {
        if ($scope.amadeus[i].ProgramPayDate === $scope.today && $scope.amadeus[i].StatusId === 3) {
          $scope.viroba = $scope.amadeus[i];
          //console.log($scope.viroba);
        }
      };
      //console.log($scope.amadeus);
    });
}
```

The response are 'n' quantity of objects. What i want to do is to show the info on my html view, but i can't. Previously i asked, and someone told me that i need to convert the objects into an array, but what i've found on the internet is not very useful for me.

Let's say i have the next response on my console:

```
{id: 1, name: "Arthur", nickname: "mercury"}
{id: 2, name: "Chuck", nickname: "lemmy"}
```

What can i do to obtain the info and show it in a table on the html view?

```
<table align="center">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Nickname</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>{{id}}</th>
        <th>{{name}}</th>
        <th>{{nickname}}</th>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

If i get only one value, it shows without problem. The issue comes when i have more than one.

Someone can help me, please?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: What's going on with that `for` loop and `if` statement? Do they have anything to do with your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the list of objects in an array which let's assume is `users` for now. `users` will look something like this

```
users = [{id: 1, name: "Arthur", nickname: "mercury"},
           {id: 2, name: "Chuck", nickname: "lemmy"}]
```

In your code try populating the `amadeus[i]` into a `users` array like below

```
function getBackAll() {
  $scope.users = []; // Or initialise this wherever logical
  $http.get('api/Invoice?')
    .then(function(data) {
      $scope.amadeus = data.data.Response;

      for (var i = 0; i < $scope.amadeus.length; i++) {
        if ($scope.amadeus[i].ProgramPayDate === $scope.today && $scope.amadeus[i].StatusId === 3) {
          $scope.users.push($scope.amadeus[i]);
          //console.log($scope.viroba);
        }
      };
      //console.log($scope.amadeus);
    });
}
```

You can use `ngRepeat` to iterate over the `users` array that you populated in your controller. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

```
<table align="center">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Nickname</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
            <th>{{user.id}}</th>
            <th>{{user.name}}</th>
            <th>{{user.nickname}}</th>
        </tr>    
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: OP is using AngularJS, so they wouldn't use handlebars to render their view.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, could you please check the updated answer. I am relatively new to Angular.

Comment: Yeah, that's more or less the way it would be done. Thanks.

Comment: Thanx to both. I'm still stuck. What cannot understand is: mi response `$scope.amadeus[i]`is asigned to the `$scope.viroba`. So, this scope i have to keep it inside of []? Sorry, maybe sounds silly, but have to much to learn yet

Comment: So, `amadeus[i]` contains the user object?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: Try checking out the `getBackAll` function that I added to the answer and the updated template.